# How to properly close a cursor in android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I have this database using sqlite, and I'm having problem with closing the cursor its saying that `Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here` here's the logcat

```
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.<init>(SQLiteCursor.java:210)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:53)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1229)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1184)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1264)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at standard.internet.marketing.mymovingfriend.SQLHandler.checkMove(SQLHandler.java:1094)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at standard.internet.marketing.mymovingfriend.ListMovingNames$3.onKey(ListMovingNames.java:98)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:3735)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1667)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1102)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2063)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2471)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2441)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1735)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-18 08:40:56.354: E/Cursor(331):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this issue's been bugging me for 3 days.

here some relevant code:

```
public class SQLHandler {

    public static final String KEY_MOVENAME = "movename";
    public static final String KEY_ID1 = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_ID5 = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_MOVEDATE = "movedate";
    public static final String KEY_TOTALMOVEWEIGHT = "totalmoveweight";
    public static final String KEY_TOTALITEM = "totalitem";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mymovingfriend";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String KEY_LISTITEMNAME = "listitemname";
    public static final String KEY_LISTITEMWEIGHT = "listitemweight";
    public static final String KEY_LISTITEMROOM = "listitemroom";

    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE1 = "movingname";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE5 = "listitem";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_1 = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE1 + " (" + 
            KEY_ID1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
            KEY_MOVEDATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_TOTALMOVEWEIGHT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_TOTALITEM + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_MOVENAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_2 = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE2 + " (" + 
            KEY_ID2 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
            KEY_ROOMMOVEHOLDER + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_ROOMWEIGHT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_ROOM + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_5 = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE5 + " (" + 
            KEY_ID5 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
            KEY_LISTITEMNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_LISTITEMWEIGHT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_LISTITEMROOM + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_1);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_2);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_3);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_4);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_5);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE1);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE2);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE3);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE4);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE5);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public SQLHandler(Context c){
        ourContext = c;
    }

    public SQLHandler open() throws SQLException{
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close(){
        ourDatabase.close();
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public long createMove(String smovename){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_MOVENAME, smovename);
        cv.put(KEY_MOVEDATE, "Not yet set");
        cv.put(KEY_TOTALMOVEWEIGHT, "0");
        cv.put(KEY_TOTALITEM, 0);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE1, null, cv);
    }

    public void createList(){

        String[] sroom = new String[]{"Kitchen", "Bedroom", "Dinning Room"};
        String[] sitem = new String[]{"Dishwasher", "Bed", "Table"};
        String[] sweight = new String[]{"40", "25", "15"};

        for (int i = 0; i < sroom.length; i++) {
            cv.put(KEY_LISTITEMROOM, sroom[i]);
            cv.put(KEY_LISTITEMNAME, sitem[i]);
            cv.put(KEY_LISTITEMWEIGHT, sweight[i]);
            ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE5, null, cv);
        }
    }

    public void setMoveDate(String smovedate, String smovename){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_MOVEDATE, smovedate);
        ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE1, cv, KEY_MOVENAME + "='" + smovename + "'", null);
    }

    public void setMoveWeight(String smoveweight, String smovename){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_TOTALMOVEWEIGHT, smoveweight);
        ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE1, cv, KEY_MOVENAME + "='" + smovename + "'", null);
    }

    public void setTotalItem(String smovename, int imoveitem){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_TOTALITEM, imoveitem);
        ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE1, cv, KEY_MOVENAME + "='" + smovename + "'", null);
    }

    public void renameRoom(String movename, String roomname, String currentroom){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_ROOM, roomname);
        ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE2, cv, KEY_ROOMMOVEHOLDER + "='" + movename + "'" + " AND " + KEY_ROOM + "='" + currentroom + "'", null);
    }

    public void setRoomWeight(String sroomweight, String smovename, String sroomname){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_ROOMWEIGHT, sroomweight);
        ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE2, cv, KEY_ROOMMOVEHOLDER + "='" + smovename + "'" + " AND " + KEY_ROOM + "='" + sroomname + "'", null);
    }

    public long addRooms(String sroommoveholder, String sroom){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_ROOMMOVEHOLDER, sroommoveholder);
        cv.put(KEY_ROOM, sroom);
        cv.put(KEY_ROOMWEIGHT, "0");
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null, cv);
    }

    public long addNewItems(String sitemmoveholder, String sroomholder, String sitemname, String sitemvalue, String sitemweight){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_ITEMMOVEHOLDER, sitemmoveholder);
        cv.put(KEY_ROOMHOLDER, sroomholder);
        cv.put(KEY_ITEMNAME, sitemname);
        cv.put(KEY_ITEMVALUE, sitemvalue);
        cv.put(KEY_ITEMWEIGHT, sitemweight);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE3, null, cv);
    }

    public void updateItems(String sitemmoveholder, String sroomholder, String sitemname, String sitemvalue, String sitemweight){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_ITEMVALUE, sitemvalue);
        cv.put(KEY_ITEMWEIGHT, sitemweight);
        ourDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE3, cv, KEY_ITEMMOVEHOLDER + "='" + sitemmoveholder + "'" + " AND " + 
                KEY_ROOMHOLDER + "='" + sroomholder + "'" + " AND " + KEY_ITEMNAME + "='" + sitemname + "'", null);
    }

    public Cursor getMove(){
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID1, KEY_MOVENAME};

        Cursor c = null;
        try {
            c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            c.close();
        }
        return c;
    }

    public String getTotalWeight(String m) throws SQLException{
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID1, KEY_MOVENAME, KEY_MOVEDATE, KEY_TOTALMOVEWEIGHT};

        Cursor c = null;
        try {
            c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, columns, KEY_MOVENAME + "= '" + m + "'", null, null, null, null);
            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                String totalWeight = c.getString(3);
                return totalWeight;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            c.close();
        }
        return null;

    }

    public String getTotalWeightLBS(String m) throws SQLException{
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID1, KEY_MOVENAME, KEY_MOVEDATE, KEY_TOTALMOVEWEIGHT};

        Cursor c = null;
        try {
            c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, columns, KEY_MOVENAME + "= '" + m + "'", null, null, null, null);
            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                int x = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(3)) * 7;
                String totalWeight = "" + x + " lbs";
                return totalWeight;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            c.close();
        }
        return null;

    }

    public String getDateMove(String md){
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID1, KEY_MOVENAME, KEY_MOVEDATE};

        Cursor c = null;try {
            c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, columns, KEY_MOVENAME + "= '" + md + "'", null, null, null, null);

            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                String moveDate = c.getString(2);
                return moveDate;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            c.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> loadRooms(String mn) throws SQLException{
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID2, KEY_ROOMMOVEHOLDER, KEY_ROOM};

        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

        Cursor c = null;
        try {
            c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE2, columns,KEY_ROOMMOVEHOLDER + "='" + mn + "'", 
                    null, null, null, null);
            int iroom = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROOM);

            for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
                array.add(c.getString(iroom));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            c.close();
        }
        return array;
    }

    public void deleteMove(String m) throws SQLException{
        ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE1, KEY_MOVENAME + "='" + m + "'", null);
        ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE2, KEY_ROOMMOVEHOLDER + "='" + m + "'", null);
        ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE3, KEY_ITEMMOVEHOLDER + "='" + m + "'", null);
        ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE4, KEY_TODOMOVE + "='" + m + "'", null);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getitems(){
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID5, KEY_ITEMNAME};
        ArrayList<String> items;
        items = new ArrayList<String>();

        Cursor c = null;
        try {
            c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE5, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

            for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
                items.add(c.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            c.close();
        }

        return items;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getitemweight(){
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID5, KEY_ITEMWEIGHT};
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

        Cursor c = null;
        try {
            c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE5, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
            for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
                items.add(c.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            c.close();
        }

        return items;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getitemclass(){
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID5, KEY_LISTITEMROOM};
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

        Cursor c = null;
        try {
            c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE5, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

            for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
                items.add(c.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            c.close();
        }

        return items;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're not closing cursor in `getDateMove`, `getTotalWeightLBS`, `loadRooms`,...

Everywhere where cursor is not needed anymore close it. In those methods use try-finally, it will guarantee to execute code in finally block even when thrown exception occur.

Change code in your methods from this:

```
try{
  // get data from cursor
} catch (Exception e) {
    c.close();
}
```

to this:

```
try {
   // get data from cursor
} catch (Exception e) {
   // exception handling
} finally {
   if(c != null){
       c.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: wait i made a typo, fix it just a sec

Comment: The exception was thrown from `checkMove` method which is not included in your code.

Comment: If you've finished reading from Cursor, close it - that's all.

Answer (score 11):

If an element is implementing AutoCloseable (like the `Cursor.class` does), I would recommend to do a `try-with-resources`, like described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).
If you use Retrolambda it has the `try-with-resources` backported.

So your code:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("tableName", columns, null, null, null, null, null);
try {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) return cursor.getString(3);
    else return null;
} finally {
   cursor.close();
}
```

would simply turn into:

```
try (Cursor cursor = db.query("tableName", columns, null, null, null, null, null)) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) return cursor.getString(3);
    else return null;
}
```

Comment: As a note, this method requires API 19

Comment: Im using it with API 11, and never received a crash while having about 3k users the last months.

Comment: Android Studio's inspector highlights the try in red with "Try-with-resources requires API level 19 (current min is 15)", however I tested and it compiles and runs fine on a phone API level 17. Apparently it's not supposed to be supported on minAPI<19. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480090/does-android-support-jdk-6-or-7/22303654#22303654 While it might work on some devices, it should NOT be recommended.

Comment: why to open cursor inside of try block ?

Comment: @Malachiasz Because its a good practice to minimize the scope of local variables (Effective Java item #45). Also delegating the cursor closing is a good idea as its less error prone and you can't forget to call `.close`.

Comment: @PaulWoitaschek: I have actually meant the 1st version, because the 2nd is not available under older Android OS versions. So the scope of variable is not smaller there, because declaration of variable happens before try block. If I close cursor in finally then I won't forget about closing. Only problem would be if somebody added some code between getting cursor from the DB and starting try - finally block.

Comment: @Malachiasz You're absolutely right about the first version. I just simplified it. Btw, retrolambda backported try-with-resources so you can use it in earlier versions of android too.

Answer (score 9):

Closing cursor in `finally` will guarantee it will be closed;

```
public void myfunc() {

    Cursor c = null;

    try {

      c = ... // Open cursor here
      return .... // maybe return something

    } finally {
       if(c != null) { c.close(); }
    } 
}
```

Comment: why to open cursor inside of try block ?

Comment: try-with-resources is much more elegant

Answer (score 8):

If you use Kotlin (also available in Java in a bit different way), and Android 4.1 and above, you can use this:

```
    cursor?.use { 
       //..do stuff
    }
```

As an example, you can check [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17852351/878126).

If you want to use Java, do something like:

```
        try (Cursor cursor = ...) {
            // do something
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

close your database in `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` method of your activity!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to close cursor inside catch block using

```
catch (Exception e) {
            c.close();
        }
```

But if you did not get any exception then how it will close

so put it inside the finally block

```
finally {
            c.close();
        }
```

Comment: oh, then try to call `startManagingCursor()` after you get the Cursor from your query.

Comment: already did that, the cursor that's been giving an error seams to be from the database and not the cursor from the activity

Answer (score -3):

Try this,

In `onStop()` or `onDestroy()`

Check whether the cursor is null

```
@Override
public void onStop(){
 Cursor cursor;

 if(cursor!=null){
  cursor.close();}
 }
```

If not then close the cursor.

**EDIT**

To Close the database object

```
DatabaseObject db;
if(db!=null)
{ db.close();}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh i see. Try closing you database object as well