# How to find the max image size supported for contacts images?

Tags: android, image, photo, resolution, android-contacts

### background

starting with jelly bean (4.1), android now supports contact images that are [720x720](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html#android-41) .

before, starting with ICS (4.0), android has supported contact images that are [256x256](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html).

and before that, contact photos had just a size of a thumbnail - 96x96

### the question

is there any function in the API that returns the max size of the contact image?

i also hope that the manufacturers didn't change the max image sizes, and even if they did and we have such a function, it would return us the correct size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

according to [this link](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2012/02/new-social-apis-in-android-ics.html), the correct way to get the max size is:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
public static int getMaxContactPhotoSize(final Context context) {
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        // Note that this URI is safe to call on the UI thread.
        final Uri uri = ContactsContract.DisplayPhoto.CONTENT_MAX_DIMENSIONS_URI;
        final String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.DisplayPhoto.DISPLAY_MAX_DIM };
        final Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        try {
            c.moveToFirst();
            return c.getInt(0);
        } finally {
            c.close();
        }
    }
    // fallback: 96x96 is the max contact photo size for pre-ICS versions
    return 96;
}
```

---

EDIT: if we use at least API 16 (4.1), it's possible to use something like:

```
@AnyThread
@RequiresPermission(anyOf = [Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS])
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
fun getMaxContactPhotoSize(context: Context): Int {
    // Note that this URI is safe to call on the UI thread.
    if (contactMaxPhotoSize > 0)
        return contactMaxPhotoSize
    val uri = ContactsContract.DisplayPhoto.CONTENT_MAX_DIMENSIONS_URI
    val projection = arrayOf(ContactsContract.DisplayPhoto.DISPLAY_MAX_DIM)
    context.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null)?.use { cursor ->
        cursor.moveToFirst()
        contactMaxPhotoSize = cursor.getInt(0)
    }
    if (contactMaxPhotoSize > 0)
        return contactMaxPhotoSize
    // fallback: 720x720 is the max contact photo size for 4.1 version
    contactMaxPhotoSize = 720
    return contactMaxPhotoSize
}
```

Comment: So... what I said, then? Cool.

Comment: yes, and if you wish that i tick your answer, please copy this code and link to your answer.

Comment: code vs no-code. That is the question ;D. In any case two good answers and both got my upvote

Comment: @leRobot Do you know perhaps about the same thing, yet for contact thumbnails ? Meaning getting the max dimensions that you get for thumbnails? Is it maybe the same, but with " THUMBNAIL_MAX_DIM" instead ?

Comment: that's what the docs say for ContactsContract.DisplayPhoto.THUMBNAIL_MAX_DIM: _Queries to (...) will contain this column, populated with the height and width (in pixels) for photo thumbnails._ As a personal note, in my app I'm only setting the display photo. I believe the system provider handles thumbnails automagically if they don't exist but the Display one does

Comment: @leRobot OK thank you. Say, have you used "openContactPhotoInputStream" with "true" as the second value? On random cases, it shows a bad quality image (actually a thumbnail), even though for the same exact contact, on another call to this function, it shows a good quality image. I've noticed it on Nexus 4 with 5.1.1, but I can't see it happen on Android 6.

Comment: that's weird because if for the same contact you're calling the last parameter boolean version of openContactPhotoInputStream, it should always return the high-res pic. I would advise attempting to get the PHOTO_ID and/or PHOTO_FILE_ID to manually query for the Uri, since the open... method might be broken accross SDKs. Link below http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html#PHOTO_ID

Comment: @leRobot Indeed. It's very weird, as it happened multiple times today, and now I can't reproduce it. So you say that the PHOTO_ID and/or PHOTO_FILE_ID  could be used instead? Do you have a recommended sample for this?

Comment: I have never done it but I google it (ended up on SF, where else :D). [This guy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13119336/1103974) seems to be doing it. See his queryContactImage method that feeds from the PHOTO_ID from the query on queryContactInfo. He then just creates a bitmap from the query. Note you can do a similar thing for PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI

Comment: Oh he also mentions some API convenience class I once looked at but didn't remember until now. It provides insight on the examples on how the contact photos are stored in a read-only directory for each contact, and how to get the two pics (thumb and full res) the system stores: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.html

Comment: @leRobot Nice. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

From [the announcement](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html#android-41):

> With Android 4.1, you can store contact photos that are as large as 720 x 720, making contacts even richer and more personal. Apps can store and retrieve contact photos at that size or use any other size needed. **The maximum photo size supported on specific devices may vary, so apps should query the built-in contacts provider at run time to obtain the max size for the current device.**

I would query for [`ContactsContract.DisplayPhoto.CONTENT_MAX_DIMENSIONS_URI`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DisplayPhoto.html#CONTENT_MAX_DIMENSIONS_URI). It should return what you're looking for.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you're under API 14, it would be 96x96 and you don't need to query, right?

Comment: i've heard that some manufacturers used higher resolutions for their contacts even on gingerbread. i'm not sure where i've got this information from though. might be wrong.

Comment: Even if that's true, you'd have to know each manufacturer's custom query, since there is no standard one before then. That could end up being a tangle mess that I'd probably avoid, and just go with the default for users <14.