# Scala 2.12 uses Java 1.8; what should we do if we are unable to upgrade to Java 1.8?

Tags: scala, scala-2.12

The release of [Scala 2.12 Milestone 1](http://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0-M1) indicates it requires Java 1.8. What should Scala users who are not able to go to Java 1.8 at this moment plan to do?

Comment: Run around in circles and panic! Seriously, I cannot imagine an alternative to the obvious answer of staying with 2.11. Backport Scala 2.12 to Java 7?

Comment: "What should I do?" not upgrading?

Comment: Guys, I happen to know the answer to this question. I just wanted to give someone else the chance to answer first. Regardless, here's the thing: stack overflow was MADE for people to get answers to actual problems. Deriding a question because you don't know the answer to it is the worst possible sin one could make here.

Comment: Android [just switched from jdk6 to jdk7](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30015557/3041008). Maintaining compatibility to over [1 billion active devices](http://thenextweb.com/google/2014/06/25/google-activations-io-2014/) should be very relevant.

Answer (score 7):

Go work somewhere that has a future :)

Banging rocks together became obsolete, and so is Java 7.

Comment: And indeed Java 7 is EOL as of April 2015. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html