# Does Android support JDK 6/JDK 7 Completely?

Tags: java, android

If No, then what are the basic features of **Java** which are **not supported** by **Android** ?

- The features which will make Android more better.

Comment: Swing ... for example.   Seriously, a large swathe of the standard Java class libraries are missing from Android.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_Android_API

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Android support JDK 6 or 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480090/does-android-support-jdk-6-or-7)

Comment: Also: http://www.zdnet.com/article/java-vs-android-apis/

Answer (score 1):

Android supports all Java 7 language features and a subset of Java 8 language features that vary by platform version.

[Android Java 8](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html)

You can also have a look at this thread [Java 6/7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20480090/5132444)