# SQLite: Must a Cursor be closed when the DB is closed?

Tags: java, sqlite, cursor

I have an open database an read out some data. After my read operations are done I close the database but not the cursor.

Do I need to close the Cursor too? 
I assume it will be done by the close of the db, but is that true?
What may happen if I don't close the Cursor?

---

```
SQLiteDatabase db = ...;
Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM foo");
//read some values using the Cursor

c.close(); //<- is this required?
db.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#ReadDbRow) says:

> When finished iterating through results, call [close()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#close()) on the cursor to release its resources.

If you do not close the cursor, you might [get an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950725/how-to-properly-close-a-cursor-in-android) later.

Comment: The question is does db.close() call close() on all its Cursors?

Comment: AFAICS it does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you close a database, the corresponding cursor will also be closed as far as I know.

An example of an exception that was thrown when I tried to traverse through a cursor (via `cursor.moveToNext()`) after having closed it's corresponding SQLite database is as follows:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because
>   the connection pool has been closed.